# OOM when using iterparse on huge XML dump file

Tags: python-3.x, xml, iterparse

Reading the large StackOverflow [XML dump file](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (`Posts.xml` `~90 GB`) through the following approach

```py
from xml.etree.cElementTree import iterparse

for evt, elem in iterparse("Posts.xml", events=('end',)):
    if elem.tag == 'row':
        user_fields = elem.attrib
```

cause OOM just iterating over the XML elements (without any memory allocation), even on a  128 GB RAM computer environment.

Since I did not get any info from documentation or other examples in the StackOverflow community, could you help me figure out how to work around it?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and put there sample input and what information do you want to get?

Comment: Maybe you specify the `row` tag (using the `tags` arg) and using the `.clear()` method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68486945/317052 for an example.

Comment: Oops...the `tags` arg is only available in lxml I think. Maybe start with just using `elem.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHaley. I've already included a `elem.clear()` without results. The only approach that seems to work is `del elem`.

Comment: Any info on how to handle this OOM issue.

Comment: Using a powershell script with XmlReader is the only way I know of parsing huge xml.  It is taking too long to down load file.  If you can post small sample of xml I will write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Daniel Haley's comments, you could try:

```py
from lxml.etree import iterparse # replace xml to lxml

for evt, elem in iterparse("Posts.xml", events=('end',), tag="row"):
    user_fields = elem.attrib
    ...
    elem.clear()
```